# Mocking a static method which is written in Scala in Java Unit test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka, jmockit, kafka-consumer-api

We are using Kafka Clients in a project.
I am trying to mock a static method from the Kafka client via JMockit :

```
    new NonStrictExpectations() {
        {
            new MockUp<Consumer>()
            {                   
                @Mock
                ConsumerConnector createJavaConsumerConnector(
                        ConsumerConfig c){
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
```

Looks like JMockit is not working due to some reason. I am sure of the syntax of JMockit for mocking static methods. This is the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matching real methods not found for the following mocks:
dispatcher.DispatcherTests$1$1#createJavaConsumerConnector(kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
```

If this does not work because the Kafka client code is in Scala, how does my program work?

Comment: I am using JMockit, and i know how to mock static methods. Its just not working for above Scala code.

Comment: sorry, mixed-up the two mocking libs

Comment: assuming `Consumer` is a Scala **object**, the way to refer to its type from Java would be `Consumer$` - so you might want to try replacing `new MockUp<Consumer>()` with `new MockUp<Consumer$>()`

Comment: Well, it does Not compile with that

Comment: Why would someone put a `MockUp` *inside* an expectation block?

Comment: Yeah, that does not add any value. I did not know about that.
But still, that does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ConsumerConnector classes - the one I was using was from the wrong package..Scala was not creating any problem here. It worked after using the right ConsumerConnector class.